# Students are assigned numbers 1 to n; 3 are chosen randomly which turn out to be 1,3,7. Given max(n) = 30 what is the MLE of n?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

The students are drawn from a discrete uniform distribution.

This is one of the exercise questions from mit.ocw. I can't quite figure out how to use the numbers selected (1,3,7) into the likelihood estimator.

P.S - This is not a homework question that I am asking others to do for me. I'm just not able to get this.

Comment: obvious correction: assigned numbers

Comment: Did you try drawing the likelihood function? (Be careful not to draw it as non-zero where it must be 0, though.)

Comment: If you write down the likelihood, it will depend on the numbers only through the fact that they have to be less than $n$ -- that's the key point

Comment: Could you please describe it in a bit more detail?

Comment: This is often discussed as the serial numbers problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability that an observation is equal to $k$ is $1/n$ if $0\leq k<n$ and 0 otherwise. The likelihood is a product of terms like that for each observation, so it's $1/n^3$ if all three numbers are less than $n$ and $0$ otherwise. The likelihood gets larger as you decrease $n$, because $1/n$ gets larger -- except that it falls to zero when you make $n$ so small that the data are impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Apologies if the question isn't clear but the question is to get the maximum likelihood estimate(point estimate) of n given the observed data (1,3,7) from the random selection. Conventionally I can't differentiate the Maximum likelihood estimator that you wrote above but from what I understand is that if I decrease n, the likelihood increases and my maximum observed data is 7. So, the estimate should be 7 because anything below that data would not be observable.